How to handle Modal Popup?
Im trying to scrape the site https://support.sw.siemens.com/en-US/.
After login site popups with cookie model popup Screenshot
How to handle this ?
I tried to narrow down to a button by XPATH and gave a click, I ended up with below error

2024-10-02 22:24:13,090 - ERROR - Navigation error: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn-reset dropdown-toggle text-inverse" id="products-subnav" data-toggle="dropdown" data-clickignore="true" aria-expanded="false">...</button> is not clickable at point (465, 110). Other element would receive the click: <div id="usercentrics-root" data-created-at="1727888038927" style=""></div>

import logging
import time  # For time tracking
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document

# Constants for URLs and directory paths
LOGIN_URL = "https://support.sw.siemens.com/signin"

DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'downloaded_pages'

# Configure the logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("web_scraping.log"), logging.StreamHandler()])


def init_web_driver():
    """
    Initializes the WebDriver with Chrome options and returns the driver object.
    """
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument("--headless")
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

def login(driver, email, password):
    """
    Logs into the Siemens support page using the provided credentials.
    """
    driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
    
    try:
        # Step 2: Enter email
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "action").click()

        # Step 3: Enter password
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "action").click()

        # Step 4: Wait for successful login
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_contains("support.sw.siemens.com"))
        logging.info("Login successful")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during login: {e}")
        driver.quit()
        raise
def navigate(driver):
    """
    Navigates to Teamcenter ITK Function Reference page.
    """
    # Click on Cokkies pop up window
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Implicit wait

# Click the 'Accept All Cookies' button using XPath or CSS Selector
    try:
        accept_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/button[1]')
        accept_button.click()
    except:
        print("Accept All Cookies button not found")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#products-subnav"))).click()
   



def main(email, password):
    """
    Main function to initiate web scraping and calculate total time taken.
    """
    start_time = time.time()  # Record start time
    driver = init_web_driver()
    
    try:
        login(driver, email, password)
        navigate(driver)
        #scrape_links(driver)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    end_time = time.time()  # Record end time
    total_time = end_time - start_time  # Calculate total time
    logging.info(f"Total time taken: {total_time:.2f} seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    email = ""  # Replace with your email
    password = ""  # Replace with your password
    main(email, password)

I know this site needs login , You can view the same popup when you just open the site in private mode https://support.sw.siemens.com/en-US/.
I need piece of code it automatically clicks on the accept the cookies button

def handle_cookies(driver, action):
    """
    Handle the cookies consent dialog.

    :param driver: The Selenium WebDriver instance.
    :param action: The action to perform on the cookies dialog ('accept' or 'deny').
    """
    shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, "usercentrics-root")
    shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root

    if action == 'accept':
        cookies_button = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")
    elif action == 'deny':
        cookies_button = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-deny-all-button']")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid cookies action. Use 'accept' or 'deny'.")

    cookies_button.click()


The cookie popup opens in a Shadow DOM and captures all click events on the document. Shadow DOM elements are encapsulated and not accessible through regular DOM traversal methods, hence the shadow_host.shadow_root.

Selenium WebElement.shadow_root
Selenium ShadowRoot Class

